# retrieve items from textboxlist in mootools

Tags: jsf-2, mootools

I have a problem with textboxlist component that I found at http://www.devthought.com/2008/01/12/textboxlist-meets-autocompletion/
I need to retrieve the selected items to bind it to a jsf backing bean, there is a method update, `update: function() {
    this.element.set('value', this.bits.getValues().join(this.options.separator));
    return this;
  }`

and I don't know how to use it.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is very old and it does not work on chrome (what I tested on).

I recommend you to move to this wonderful solid plugin which uses latest mootools,works well in every browser, more robust:

http://julesjanssen.github.io/chosen/